# How to have toggle on or off inside a button should be supported for a wide range mobile and tablet devices?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrapping

I have a Button some xyz and it is not clickble and and inside this button right to it i should have a toggle button on/off i have achieve this to some extent but it is not getting achieved for smaller devices.

```
<td id="onoffbtns">
            <div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default">off</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger active">on</button>
                </div>
            </td>
```

I will be thank full to the person who helps me

Comment: For custom buttons like this, you need to use images for toggling effect and using images which will suit to all device resolution.